# Splunk: Escaping "<" ">" from the dashboard's source code

Tags: regex, splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to put below search query as base search in the dashboard's source code.Getting "unexpected close tag" error because of ">" and "<" which encloses new field name "Env" extracted from rex.

```
<search id="base_search">
<query>index=_internal earliest=-1d latest=now | rex field=host "(?P<Env>[[:alpha:]]{2})\-[[:alpha:]]+" </query>
</search>
```

Using backslash is not fixing.Can someone help me out here.

Comment: I tried backslashes ( both double and single ) .Not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your query in `CDATA` tags, as described at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.4/Viz/OverviewofSimplifiedXML

```
<search id="base_search">
<query>
<![CDATA[
index=_internal earliest=-1d latest=now | rex field=host "(?P<Env>[[:alpha:]]{2})\-[[:alpha:]]+" 
]]>
</query>
</search>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the XML entities: `&lt;` & `&gt;`

If you construct a search in the UI view, then go to edit source, you'll see that's how Splunk converts it under the hood